# Pork sausage - difference in food guidelines

Tags: food-safety, sausages

I'm wondering why Still Tasty says that fresh pork breakfast sausage lasts 1-2 days refrigerated but the company that I talked to that makes sausages say eight days from the packing date. http://www.stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/18275

Still Tasty also says that ground pork can last 3-4 days, I'm not sure why sausages wouldn't last as long as ground pork. http://www.stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/18065

I called the company that makes the sausage and they said it's fine for up to eight days. I hate to throw it away after four days but not sure which source to believe. Thanks!

Comment: Believe the source you got the sausages from. Don't assume all sausages are the same.

Comment: It's possible that Still Tasty is assuming an opened package, and the manufacturer is assuming that you haven't broken the seal yet.  Very often, the shelf life dramatically drops once you've opened things.  (eg, UHT milk like Paramlat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The StillTasty link you give for the sausages is for all types of fresh, raw sausages, not just pork. That's why it's labeled "SAUSAGES (INCLUDING PORK, BEEF, CHICKEN OR TURKEY) — FRESH, RAW".

Most likely, they're getting the 1–2-day limit from the chicken sausages (which are likely to have a higher initial bacteria load than pork or beef). Note that they give the same 1–2-day limit for [raw ground chicken](http://www.stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/16798).

That said, if the manufacturer gives you specific advice, it overrides the general advice from sites like StillTasty. They know their specific product. Their specific formulation probably includes things (salt, acids, preservatives, various spices) which slow bacterial growth, thus keeping it good longer.